# Show that $\int fd\mu>0$ iff $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I’m practicing for my real analysis exam coming up and am specifically looking at problem 3 in section 3A from Sheldon Axler’s [Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf). The question says:

> Suppose $(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space and $f:X\to[0,\infty]$ is an $S$-measurable function. Prove that $$\int fd\mu>0 \quad\text{if and only if}\quad \mu(\{x\in X:f(x)>0\})>0.$$

See definitions 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3 ($S$-partition, lower Lebesgue sum, Lebesgue integral of nonnegative function). I have a solution, but I don't know if my solution is correct, so I was wondering if someone could verify. Here it is:

**Proof:** Let $F=\{x\in X:f(x)>0\}$. 
($\implies$) We prove this direction by contrapositive. Suppose $\mu(F)=0$. Let $P=\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ be an arbitrary $S$-partition. Then we have that
$$\begin{align*}
L(f;P)&=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i)\inf_{A_i}f\\
&=\sum_{A_i\not\subset F}\mu(A_i)\inf_{A_i}f\\
&=\sum_{A_i\not\subset F}\mu(A_i)\cdot 0 = 0.
\end{align*}$$
Since $P$ is arbitrary, this shows every Lebesgue lower sum of $f$ is $0$ so that $\int fd\mu=0$. 
($\impliedby$) Suppose $\mu(F)>0.$ Note that since $F=f^{-1}((0,\infty])$, $(0,\infty]$ is a Borel set, and $F$ is $S$-measurable, that $F\in S.$ So then $Q=\{F,X\setminus F\}$ is an $S$-partition, and
$$\int fd\mu\geq L(f;Q)=\mu(F)\inf_{F}f+\mu(X\setminus F)\inf_{X\setminus F}f=\mu(F)\inf_{F}f>0. $$

Comment: You write $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\})>0$ in the title and $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>0\}) = 0$ in the question body. I assume that you mean the former.

Comment: @MartinR yes that is what I meant, thank you!

Comment: What if $\inf_F f  = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last bit is not correct. Notice that $\inf_F f$ can be $0$ so $\mu(F)\inf_F f$ can be $0$, it is not always $>0$ as you said.

The other direction looks good to me though!

Hint: for the case where $\mu(F)>0$ is given you need to use continuity of measure. It will be true that $\mu(f>\epsilon)>0$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and then you can use your same proof strategy, since $\inf f\ge \epsilon>0$ will be true.

"Another" (it is basically the same, just perhaps more conceptual) proof for the first direction might be: $$\int_Xf\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{X\setminus F}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{f=0}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=0$$Where the first equality is valid by virtue of $x\in X\setminus F$ for almost every $x\in X$.

Comment: Ahhh got it, thank you! Yes I was worried about that last bit for the reasons you said.

Comment: Is the $\epsilon$ just $1/n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by Archimedean Property?

Comment: @blakedylanmusic This isn't really about the Archimedean property, though, because of this property you can indeed always choose $\epsilon=1/n$, but you don't have to. Second hint: continuity of measure tells you: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu(A_j)$$Where $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq\cdots$ are all measurable. Can you express $F$ in a similar way that involves $(f>\epsilon)$? (indeed, with $\epsilon:=1/n$ being the natural choice)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were referring to that property when you said continuity of measure. Yes, $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{x\in X:f(x)>1/n\}$ and the sequence of the sets $\{x\in X:f(x)>1/n\}$ is increasing. So $\mu(F)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>1/n\})$. Feeling confused as to how that connects to this though.

Comment: @blakedylanmusic Well you know $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu((f>1/n))>0$. Appeal now to the definition of limit. If $\mu(F)=\infty$ then there must be some $N$ that $\mu((f>1/n))>1$ for all $n>N$. Otherwise, take $\varepsilon:=\mu(F)/2$. Then there must be $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|\mu((f>1/n))-\mu(F)|<\mu(F)/2$. Then $\mu((f>1/n))>\mu(F)/2$. So in either case we manage to find some quantity $\epsilon:=1/N>0$ with $\mu((f>\epsilon))>0$, and we are done because: $$\int f\ge\int_{(f>\epsilon)}f\ge\epsilon\cdot\mu((f>\epsilon))>0$$

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @blakedylanmusic You’re welcome!